# C/C++, оптимизации компилятора для выражения (a*b)/a != b

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Мне необходимо проверить, возникает ли переполнение при умножении двух беззнаковых целых. Делаю это так:

```
size_t cio_uint_mul(const unsigned int _a,
                    const unsigned int _b)
{
    if ( (_a > 0) && (_b > 0) )
    {
        if ((_a * _b) / _a != _b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

После знакомства с тем, как компилятор может оптимизировать код, меня терзают сомнения, не превратит ли он второй if в TRUE?

Может, для того, чтобы произошло именно то, что мне нужно, нужно делать так:

```
size_t cio_uint_mul(const unsigned int _a,
                    const unsigned int _b)
{
    if ( (_a > 0) && (_b > 0) )
    {
        const unsigned int c = _a * _b;
        if (c / _a != _b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

?

У меня развивается панический страх оптимизатора...

Comment: Вообще-то не должен, именно потому, что (a*b)/a не всегда равно b. А вот выделите ли вы под это произведение отдельную переменную или нет - вот тут он запросто может ее соптимизировать...

Comment: Нет, разумеется, никакой компилятор не может превратить это в `true`, если не будет знать заранее, что переполнение невозможно. В любом случае, ваш второй вариант в этом плане ничем не отличается от первого.

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: @AnT, а как же UB?

Comment: @Qwertiy UB в смысле результата умножения?

Comment: @Harry, signed overflow - это UB. В моём ответе, кстати, есть пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, но в данном случае намеренно используются unsigned типы. Никакого signed overflow тут нет.

Comment: @AnT, да, с unsigned нет. Просто ваши с Harry комментарии звучат так, как будто это верно для любых типов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть чудный сервис https://gcc.godbolt.org/ - можно взять свой код и посмотреть, что будут делать разные компиляторы. К примеру, gcc 8.1 генерирует достаточно простой код

```
cio_uint_mul(unsigned int, unsigned int):
  test edi, edi
  je .L3
  test esi, esi
  je .L3
  mov eax, edi
  xor edx, edx
  imul eax, esi
  div edi
  cmp eax, esi
  sete al
  movzx eax, al
  ret
.L3:
  mov eax, 1
  ret
```

Intel компилятор делает такой же длины код, clang - чуточку длинее (но не обязательно (быстрее или медленнее - это надо проверять отдельно). Студийный компилятор делает что то большое. Но все компиляторы честно умножают и делят. И это логично - если a и b будут большими, то условие может не выполнятся.

В втором случае Вы пытаетесь "обмануть компилятор". Вот только новый код абсолютно такой же (логически). Но если все таки хочется его "обмануть", то нужно как минимум добавить `volatile` для с, что бы компилятор его читал-писал гарантированно. Но и тут достаточно спорно, что будет делать компилятор в этом случае с оптимизацией.

P.S. как правильно заметили ниже, для знаковых типов переполнение не определено и компилятор имеет право сделать оптимизацию (и даже больше - он ее делает gcc с 7.1, clang c 3.4,  а студийный похоже не умеет). Второй пример также компилирует и оптимизирует также. Но если хочется отключить - делайте с c модификатором `volatile`.

Comment: Ассемблерный листинг - не гарантия, что в дальнейшем поведение не изменится.

Comment: Если наблюдаемое поведение не поменяется, то содержимое листинга ничего не значит

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется у вас тут сам подход не правильный. Для проверки на переполнение будет достаточно расширить каждое число, перемножить их и проверить, не получилось ли число слишком велико.

```
int cio_uint_mul(const uint32_t a, const uint32_t b)
{
    return ((uint64_t) 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) < (((uint64_t) a) * ((uint64_t) b));
}
```

Если же умножение с большей разрядностью не поддерживается, то проверку на переполнение можно произвести после разложения:

> a * b = (ahigh * 2 ^ 16 + alow) * (bhigh * 2 ^ 16 + blow)

Comment: Подход абсолютно правильный. Использование 64-разрядных целых недопустимо, тк код разрабатывается в том числе и под платформу, где НЕТ 64-битных целых. Про проверку при помощи разложения я что-то не совсем понял.

Comment: @Максим В вашем вопросе таких деталей не было. А за счет такого разложения можно проводить операции в числах в половину разряда.

Answer (score 1):

Для беззнаковых чисел компилятор обязан нормально выполнять переполнение, поэтому всё должно быть хорошо. А вот если бы числа были знаковыми, тогда мог бы оптимизировать.

https://ideone.com/41Jmga

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(f, type) int f(type a, type b)  { return a && b ? a * b / b == a : 1; }

CHECK(checki, int)
CHECK(checku, unsigned)

int main(void)
{
  int ia, ib;
  unsigned ua, ub;

  scanf("%d%d%u%u", &ia, &ib, &ua, &ub);

  printf("%d %d", checki(ia, ib), checku(ua, ub));

  return 0;
}
```

```
72000 72000 72000 72000
```

```
1 0
```